# Criteria Query 2, query through 3 entities level

Tags: java, criteria-api

I am learning Criteria API, I encounter an issue to create my query.
Here is my structure :

An Admin has a list of Groups, A Group has a list of Admins (so ManyToMany relationship)

A Group has a list of Companies, A Company has one Group (so OneToMany)

To find all groups of an Admin I created this request :

```
@Override
public List<Group> getAllGroupsManagedByAdmin(Admin admin)
{
 final CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
 final CriteriaQuery<Group> query = cb.createQuery(Group.class);
 final Root<Admin> admins = query.from(Admin.class);

 query.where(cb.equal(admins.get(Admin_.id), admin.getId()))
 .select(admins.join(Admin_.groups));

 return this.entityManager.createQuery(query).getResultList();
}
```

Now I'm trying to find all companies of one group but be sure this group is managed by the admin provided in parameter, the method definition is :

```
public List<Company> getCompaniesByGroupIdManagedByAdmin(String groupId, Admin admin)
```

But all my drafts failed at this moment. Could someone give me some help ?
Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally find by myself, the solution is easier what I expected :

```
public List<Company> getCompaniesByGroupIdManagedByAdmin(String groupId, Admin admin)
{
    final CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
    final CriteriaQuery<Company> query = cb.createQuery(Company.class);
    final Root<Admin> admins = query.from(Admin.class);

    final Join<Admin, Group> groups = admins.join(Admin_.groups);

    final Predicate[] predicates = new Predicate[2];

    predicates[0] = cb.equal(admins.get(Admin_.id), admin.getId());
    predicates[1] = cb.equal(groups.get(Group_.id), groupId);

    query.where(predicates)
    .select(groups.join(Group_.companies));

    return this.entityManager.createQuery(query).getResultList();
}
```